# opencv: error after conversion of an iplimage to a mat

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, iplimage

i need to convert a mat to iplimage and back, in order to draw a line.
My code so far:

```
Mat mat = imread(path);
Point p,q;
...
imwrite(path1,mat1);
IplImage img = mat1;
cvDrawLine(&img,p,q,Scalar(0,0,255));
mat1 = Mat(&img);    //i also tried mat1=&img;
imwrite(path2,mat1);
```

the first imwrite works, but at the second, i get an exception. Any ideas?

Comment: You can draw a line with.... "cv::line". You should really avoid obsolete C stuff like iplimage.

Comment: thank you, didnt find that function...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`cv::cvarrToMat`**](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cvarrtomat) to convert `CvMat`, `IplImage`, or `CvMatND` to `Mat`.

For your case, it will be like:

```
mat1 = cv::cvarrToMat(&img, true);
```

---

PS: As commented by @Miki, you should avoid obsolete C OpenCV APIs. Using C++ APIs, it will simply be:

```
cv::line(mat1, p, q, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
```